# Passing a section title through to a tcolorbox in a \titleformat call

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox, titlesec

I have been trying to use a tcolorbox within a titleformat call to use part of an image in each section title. Unfortunately, it seems as though it gets stuck with passing the section title through to the tcolornox, such that calling {#1} within the tcolorbox throws up an error

```
\titleformat{\section}
  [block]
  {\center\normalfont\bfseries\color{Red}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, width=\textwidth,
      watermark graphics=graphic.jpg, watermark opacity=0.2,
      watermark overzoom=1.0, colback=Red!10, colframe=Red!80,
      sharp corners, valign=center, height=1.5cm]
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{#1}
        \end{center}
    \end{tcolorbox}
  }
```

The error message that comes up at each section call:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \ttlf@section

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: To note, the code works when #1 is replaced with 'test', however the section title is printed underneath the tcolorbox rather than within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load `titlesec` with the `explicit` option, but I usually don't recommend this. The last mandatory argument of `\titleformat` can end with a one-argument macro that will be fed with the section title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\colorlet{Red}{red!60}

\newcommand{\formatsectiontitle}[1]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    width=\textwidth,
    watermark graphics=example-image, % <--- fix the file name
    watermark opacity=0.2,
    watermark overzoom=1.0,
    colback=Red!10,
    colframe=Red!80,
    sharp corners,
    valign=center,
    height=1.5cm
  ]
    \centering\bfseries #1
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries\color{Red}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\formatsectiontitle}

\begin{document}

\section{Test title}

Here the section starts.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much

Comment: @MargotRosa You still have to manage the section numbers; or are you omitting them throughout?

Comment: Yeah, omitting them was intentional